# FFmpeg : How to get last frame from a video

Tags: video, ffmpeg, android, frame

I have a video.mp4  file i want to get last frame from video/mp4 file and save as a image in local.
If it is possible then please suggest me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 26):

Use

```
ffmpeg -sseof -3 -i input -update 1 -q:v 1 last.jpg
```

This will seek to the last three seconds of the input and output all frames. But since `-update 1` is set, each frame will be overwritten to the same file, leaving only the last frame remaining.

Comment: This isn't a problem to me, but for some reason the PNG version of this -- `ffmpeg -sseof -3 -i input -update 1 -vframes 1 last.png` -- doesn't work.

Comment: Share full log.

Comment: `ffmpeg -sseof -3 -i AVI300.avi -update 1 -vframes 1 last.png` = `ffmpeg version N-91990-g49c67e79ca Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers\built with gcc 8.2.1 (GCC) 20180813\[...]\-sseof value seeks to before start of file AVI300.avi; ignored\Input #0, avi, from 'AVI300.avi':\Duration: 00:00:02.60, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 36 kb/s[...]` - not the full log, but it has the important parts I think. I tried `ffmpeg -sseof -3 -i input -update 1 -vframes 1 last.png` with a .mov video and it also didn't work.

Comment: Open a new Q and include command and *full* log.

Comment: This outputs an mp4.

Comment: @tommy.carstensen Open a new Q with command and full log.

Comment: @Gyan No, you should fix your answer.

Comment: Why do you think it outputs a MP4?

Comment: @tommy.carstensen Works for me outputting to PNG on ffmpeg v4.4. Are you getting an MP4 file out? Does it have the same name as the output file you specify (last.png)? Is it just one frame or the last 3 seconds of the input?

Comment: Any reason not to seek to the last 1 second, or the last .25 seconds, or...?

Comment: Some containers don't have a global KF index so ffmpeg can only seek forward in time. If you seek to the last second, there may not be any KF after that point and there will be no output. 3 is a compromise value - not too long but should contain a KF.